# c# Process Arguments and Missing Output

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm using an `FFMPEG Process` to gather some information on a file:

```
private void GatherFrames()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + filePath + "\"";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    if (!process.Start())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error starting");
        return;
    }
    StreamReader reader = process.StandardError;
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        outputRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");
    }
    process.Close();
}
```

This seems to works fine. Now I want to get just the `FrameRate`, and [thanks to other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110264/how-to-find-frames-per-second-of-any-video-file), I've found that `ffprobe` can be used to do just that:

```
public void GetFrameRate()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffprobe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v 0 -of compact=p=0 -select_streams 0 -show_entries stream = r_frame_rate \"" + filePath + "\"";
    Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.Arguments);
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo);

    if (!process.Start())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error starting");
        return;
    }

    StreamReader reader = process.StandardError;
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    process.Close();
}
```

This does not seem to work at all. The process starts, but does not return what I expect to be returned.

If I run the command manually, I do the following in `cmd.exe`:

```
> e:
> cd "FILE_PATH"
> ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0 -select_streams 0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate "FILE_NAME.mp4"
r_frame_rate=60/1
```

Note: `-show_entries stream = r_frame_rate` does not work, only `-show_entries stream=r_frame_rate` without the spaces.

---

I'm not sure how to properly go about doing this with a `Process`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your argument and got the output through `StandardOutput` property.
Please just change your code to below and try it again.

```
StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
```